# How to do a "regular" pip installation from a wheel file

Tags: pip

When I do a `pip freeze`, most of the output looks like this:

```
addict==2.4.0
aiohttp==3.9.1
aiosignal==1.3.1
asgiref==3.7.2
astroid==3.0.2
async-timeout==4.0.3
attrdict==2.0.1
```

However, there is one package that I installed from a wheel file with `pip install package.whl`, and its output looks like this:

```
package @ file:///some/directory/package-0.17-py3-none-any.whl#sha256=0c54eaxf...
```

Why is it different from the others?  Is there a way to install from a wheel file so that  the installation is the same as all the other packages?